# Solution for A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckDuplicatesRunnable

Tags: android

A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckDuplicatesRunnable

I found the solution for this error as follows Please answer for accuracy

buid.gradle(Module:app)

```
    dependencies {
  implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.6.1' // Delete
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.6.1'// Delete
}
```